# how to convert particular time into UTC timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm having a time in this format like

```
var time = "22:00:00"
```

I need to convert this into UTC time format like 1567890764
I'm using this one to convert time into UTC.

```
Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) //it return current UTC timestamp
```

how to pass the "time" variable and get UTC timestamp for that particular time?

Comment: There is no such thing as a _"UTC time format"_. That timestamp you posted is a full _date_. There's a year / month / day etc in there as well. `1567890764` is the timestamp for _"GMT: Saturday, September 7, 2019 9:12:44 PM"_

Comment: Yeah i need the timestamp of today date with time "22:00:00". How to achieve that only by having time = "22:00:00"

Comment: 22:00:00 has a different equivalent UTC time in every timezone with a different offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create UTC Timestamps with the full date. 
You can use the .getTime() function of the Date object. You will get the milliseconds since 1970/01/01 and then divide it with 1000 to get the seconds.

```
let datestring = "2017-10-21 13:22:01";
let date = new Date(datestring);
console.log(date.getTime() / 1000); // will return 1508584921
```

You can also take a look at [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) which is great for handling Date and Time in Javascript.

EDIT: 
If you want todays date 22:00:00 just init new Date and set the time like this:

```
let date = new Date();
date.setHours(22);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
```

Comment: I'm not having date along with that time string. I'm just having time = "22:00:00" how to get utc of that time

Comment: I updated my answer If you want todays date 22:00:00